# Защита сайта

Tags: защита, php

Cупер-пупер-самый-лучший-в-мире-мессенджер  временно отключен на доработку. Ибо его разнесли в пух и прах.

Comment: @Deus Если пользоваться такими фичами, как: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php, то возможность инъекции стремится к нулю. В mysqli такие фичи тоже присутствуют.

Comment: @lampa, фичи это хорошо, охота самому вникнуть. Прочитаешь 9000 книг - ничего толком не скажут. Сайт же Мержевича хакнули, а я по его учебникам учил css.

Comment: @Deus, галерею сами сделали ?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, сайт удалил. Да - все сам.Из готового использовал только datepicker.

Comment: @Deus, мне лично нравиться ход ваших мыслей )) 
Доработайте +как надо = и все, удачи!

Comment: @lampa, по поводу. Дело в том, что до запроса все post-параметры проверяются регуляркой на допустимые символы и проходят очистку - html_special_chars, real_escape_string. Разве этого мало для защиты от инъекции?

Comment: @Deus сама суть sql инъекции в неиспользовании prepared statement, тут и вникать нечего, либо в запросах константы, либо prepared. лучше вникните как prepared работает.

Comment: @eicto, вникаю. Как же раньше до bind и prepare боролись с иньекцией,а?

Comment: @Deus я думаю, уже не важно, как раньше с этим боролись, а важно, какие сейчас есть более лучшие средства. Их нужно учить.

P.S. в одном проекте тоже занимался проверкой вход. данных (всех) с помощью регулярок - плохое это дело :)

Comment: [вот так и боролись](http://drupal.org/search/site/sql%20injection)

Comment: @Deus
> Как же раньше до bind и prepare боролись с иньекцией,а?

[и вот так ещё][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/wPs2v4qz

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это вообще не вопрос.

Comment: Был вопросом (см. историю), но автор его совсем испортил. Здесь обсуждался сайт,который сейчас не существует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnQQE.png]

Comment: @lampa, круто, а что это было?))

Comment: @Deus ничего хорошего :)

Comment: Десять баллов!!!!! Думал такое же сделать, но чего-то не проверил.

Comment: @lampa, по-ходу я проверял картинки яваскриптом, а на сервере без проверок - так?

Comment: @Deus ну да, так и есть) мускуль вроде молчит

Comment: а не, у вас в запросах также большие дырища))

Comment: @lampa, ничего не понимаю, у меня ведь при регистрации пароль кодируется, как вообще такой запрос работает??

Comment: @Deus а логин?

Comment: @lampa, тоже кодировать, что ли???

Answer (score 1):

1) Дата рождения: 1960-01-01 - пятидесяти пяти летние в пролете. Пичалька.
2) При отключении яваскрипта все пропадает. Должно хотя бы сообщение об ошибке вылезать
3) http://www.cassandra.hol.es/php/ - каталожек. :) 
Ну и так далее. Думаю, взломщики найдут больше

Comment: @knes,отлично-отлично. Залил в каталожек пустой файл index.php. Но это же не выход из положения?

Comment: используйте htaccess для закрытия/открытия чего либо

Comment: Deus, да, не выход. Обычно заливают index.html, чтобы даже при рухнувшем интерпретаторе и дефолтном .htaccess оно все равно выдало что надо.

Таки да, devian прав. Это еще лучше, но index все же можно залить в каждую директорию. Чтобы наверняка.

Comment: .htassecc - это такие дебри - ассемблер отдыхает. Нужно вникать.

Comment: @Deus, чаво? Закрыть через него директорию - элементарно и удобно.

Comment: Нужно вникать, без этого сейчас нельзя. А пока вникаете, на первое время, сойдет костыль с индексом

Comment: @lampa, так как скрипт вместо картинки выгрузить на сервер через input type='file'? Я взял скрипт, поменял расширение на jpg, залил его на сервер. Ну и что? Нужно чтобы он еще и работал!

Comment: @istem, ща доработаю сайт, если захочешь - поковыряешь. Вот - lampa разворотил его в пух и прах. Есть над чем задуматься.

Answer (score 0):

1) ник как то неограниченный

2) Местопребывание можно задать на несуществующий )

3) нажать "войти", вылезет сообщение, нажать "зарегестрироваться", сообщение осталось )

странный месенджер, зачем в общении скрол и страницы? я долго пытался прокрутить, потом заметил странички )

*когда дома буду, помучаю сайтик )*

Comment: @IVsevolod, пока работает ))

Comment: @IVsevolod, очень странно, стояло ограничение на 20 символов для ника. Во блин.

Comment: @Deus вечером буду мучать )

Comment: @IVsevolod, до вечера он может не дожить!

Comment: @lampa, как я ни стараюсь, не могу протулить на свой сайт как вы - вместо картинки - скрипт. Яваскрипт не дает. Как это сделать?!!

Comment: Например, пересобрать страницу с чуток измененным яваскриптом. Проще всего через inspect element.
Там, где проверка поставьте true. =)

Впрочем, вы можете это изменить прямо в файле, а потом прикручивать проверку на сервере

Comment: @Deus да я тупо создал html файл с формой, через которую и залил :)